Are the relations in the Blessed Trinity transcendental relations?
According Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P., The Trinity and God the Creator, ch. 2, q. 28 "The Divine Relations", § "Philosophical Notes on the Idea of Relation and Its Division", p. 111:

Real relations are divided into transcendental and predicamental. A transcendental relation is the order included in the essence of a thing as, for example, the soul’s transcendental order to the body, that of matter to form, essence to being, accident to the subject, science to its object, etc. All these things have these relations by their very essence, and the transcendental relation perdures even when the term disappears.

With this said, are the personal relations in the Blessed Trinity transcendental relations as defined by Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.?

What is your own experience of knowing the Father and the Son, in one Holy Spirit ? What would you say yourself about this question ?

Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

I think even the most basic question (Which this is not), that the person who posed the question already knows an answer to (which doesn't seem to be the case here), would still deserve to get a good answer instead of a "what do you think"

@Wyrsa The question is about relationships.

@NigelJ the question is about the relations between the Persons of the Trinity, which is a specific theological concept. It's not about relationships the way the word is used colloquially.

@jaredad7  The relationship between the Fathet and the Son is that of a begetting, through one Eternal Spirit. And the only way this is known and experienced by humanity is by a new birth, also of One Eternal Spirit. This is made clear in scripture.

What definition does Garrigou Lagrange give for a predicamental real relation? They are definitely real relations, but it would help to have the other type of real relation defined.

@NigelJ the question is very clearly asking about a particular theological term. The OP's personal experience is not relevant and the Scriptural framework is related but a bit more remote.

@eques So - completely theoretical. Or terminological, as you say.

I wouldn't necessarily say either of those. Not everyone shares the modern predilection to dismiss philosophy as real knowledge.

Wuellner, S.J., Dictionary of Scholastic Philosophy p. 265 defines:

transcendental (necessary) relation, a connection between one thing and another that is so necessary to the subject that it cannot be without that relation; hence, it is either identified with its whole essence, is a condition of its being, or necessarily follows its being and essence so that loss of this relation would imply the destruction of that being or essence: as, the dependence of creature on the Creator is a transcendental relation. This usage, at least as old as John of St. Thomas (1589-1644), is sometimes regarded as a misnomer and not as a true relation.

Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P., divides "real relation" into (ibid.):

transcendental or (vel) essential
predicamental or (vel) accidental

The Divine Relations, being His essence Itself, can't be accidental; there are no accidents in God (i.e., no beings added or accreting onto God; He is absolutely simple).
So, that leaves that the Divine Relations are real, transcendental relations.

The Persons of the Trinity are related to one another on account of the Divine operations of knowing and loving, which have their impetus and terminus both in the Divine Essence (that is, self-knowledge and self-love). St. Thomas covers this in Summa Theologica I q. 28 (refer to the whole question). In article 2 of that question, Aquinas explains how the relations are essential and not accidental or extrinsic to God, that they are contained within the Divine Essence. Since transcendental relations, according to the definition above, seem always to unite things which are not mixed in God (act/potency, matter/form, being/essence), I have to conclude that the relations between the Trinitarian Persons is not transcendental.

The Father and the Son are related due to a begetting.

@NigelJ what is your point?

I mostly follow your outline, but being and essence are the same in God -- we wouldn't say they are unrelated. We might say that being is in the essence of God, wouldn't we?

@eques I agree with your comment, but I'm not certain what the confusion is.

@jaredad7 which confusion? I think Geremia's answer makes it clear they have to be transcendental.
